# Donde van los protectores de cabecera en archivos fuente de C++

Tags: c++

Quiero dividir mi código en varios ficheros pero no se donde se colocan los llamados guardias de cabecera. Van en geometria.cpp o goemetria.hpp

Geometria.hpp

```
#ifndef HIPOTENUSA
#define HIPOTENUSA

float hipotenusa(float, float);

#endif
```

geometria.cpp

```
#ifndef HIPOTENUSA
#define HIPOTENUSA

#include <cmath>
#include "geometria.hpp"

float hipotenusa(float a, float b){
    return std::sqrt(a*a+b*b);
}
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <geometria.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::cout << hipoenusa(34.34,234.78) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Otra cosa que no se es si geometria.cpp debe #incluir geometria.hpp para que tenga acceso a los prototipos de función, yo se he puesto el #include.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para entender dónde van las guardas de inclusión<sup>1</sup> (no protectores de cabecera) debemos entender el...

#### Proceso de compilación de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)

En C++ el código pasa por [nueve fases [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases) para generar un archivo ejecutable:

1. Se ajustan los caracteres del código para que coincidan con los caracteres que acepta el estándar.
2. Las instrucciones multilínea se juntan en una sola línea.
3. Se eliminan los comentarios.
4. **Se ejecuta el preprocesador**.
5. Los caracteres de los literales de carácter o cadena se pasan a la codificación del sistema.
6. Se concatenan los literales de cadena adyacentes.
7. Se compila.
8. Se examinan las instancias de plantillas que han sido instanciadas.
9. Se enlazan todos los componentes en el archivo ejecutable.

El punto más relevante para tu pregunta es el cuarto, ya que una instrucción `#include` es una directiva de preprocesador.

Cuando se procesa una instrucción `#include` lo que hace el preprocesador es copiar todo el contenido de ese archivo en el archivo que se está compilando; vamos a suponer que tenemos los siguientes archivos:

`A.hpp`

```
void a() {}
```

`B.hpp`

```
#include "A.hpp"
void b() {}
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"
int main() { return 0; }
```

En la cuarta fase de compilación, el archivo `main.cpp` pasará por los siguientes estados:

1. Original.

   ```
   #include "A.hpp"
   #include "B.hpp"
   int main() { return 0; }
   ```
2. Se procesa la primera inclusión.

   ```
   void a() {}
   #include "B.hpp"
   int main() { return 0; }
   ```
3. Se procesa la segunda inclusión.

   ```
   void a() {}
   #include "A.hpp"
   void b() {}
   int main() { return 0; }
   ```
4. De manera recursiva, se procesa la segunda inclusión.

   ```
   void a() {}
   void a() {}
   void b() {}
   int main() { return 0; }
   ```

En el momento de compilar, tendremos un fallo por re-declarar la función `a`. Veamos que pasaría con guardas de inclusión, `main.cpp` no cambiaría:

`A.hpp`

```
#ifndef A
#define A
void a() {}
#endif
```

`B.hpp`

```
#ifndef B
#define B
#include "A.hpp"
void b() {}
#endif
```

En la cuarta fase de compilación, el archivo `main.cpp` pasará por los siguientes estados:

1. Original.

   ```
   #include "A.hpp"
   #include "B.hpp"
   int main() { return 0; }
   ```
2. Se procesa la primera inclusión.

   ```
   #ifndef A
   #define A
   void a() {}
   #endif
   #include "B.hpp"
   int main() { return 0; }
   ```
3. Se procesa la segunda inclusión.

   ```
   #ifndef A
   #define A
   void a() {}
   #endif
   #ifndef B
   #define B
   #include "A.hpp"
   void b() {}
   #endif
   int main() { return 0; }
   ```
4. De manera recursiva, se procesa la segunda inclusión.

   ```
   #ifndef A
   #define A
   void a() {}
   #endif
   #ifndef B
   #define B
   #ifndef A
   #define A
   void a() {}
   #endif
   void b() {}
   #endif
   int main() { return 0; }
   ```
5. Aplicamos las guardas de inclusión:

   ```
   // A definido
   void a() {}


   // B definido
   /* #ifndef A 'A' ya está definido, este código desaparece
   #define A
   void a() {}
   #endif */
   void b() {}

   int main() { return 0; }
   ```

---

<sup>1</sup>Del inglés [*include guard*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard).

Answer (score 0):

Intenta que tus ficheros tengan la extensión `.h` y a este fichero incluir `#pragma once`  luego en el programa principal que tiene la extensión `.cpp` agregar el fichero mediante:           `#include "nombredefichero.h"`  así entre comillas, Aquí te dejo como funciona [#pragma once](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragma_once) saludos

Comment: #pragma once no es oficial de C++ y aun no se si está disponible para Mingw que es el compilador que uso

Answer (score 0):

Los protectores van en los archivos de cabecera: .hpp en c++ y .h en c.
Te dejo un link con información: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard